# Snake Movement in snake game in C++

Tags: c++

I am a beginner at C++ and only familiar with basic c++ libraries and functions. I am trying to make a snake game(without graphics) on the console. Everything worked fine till I reached the snake movement part. Now, the snake only moves in a particular direction if I keep on pressing a certain character. How can I basically make it move until another character is pressed just like standard snake game?
Following is the function for snake movement:

```
void snake_movement(){

    switch (getch())
    {
    case 'w':
        y_cordinate--;
        break;
    case 'a':
        x_cordinate--;
        break;
    case 's':
        y_cordinate++;
        break;    
    case 'd':
        x_cordinate++;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Kindly do consider the fact that I am a beginner while answering as I might not be able to understand the logic if a difficult library or programming words are used

Comment: Instead of changing the snake's position, you can change a snake's *velocity*, which includes direction. And For every loop, change snake's position according to it's velocity.

Comment: 김선달  Sir I am unfamiliar with velocity term. Is there a particular function pertaining to velocity?

Comment: No I meat it literally. Just simple physics. An object's position changes with time\*velocity. In your case, time can be replaced with a loop (maybe 1sec for a loop? up to you), and velocity can be (1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, 1) or (0, -1) in 2D x-y coordinates. Update snake's position with adding velocity*t.

Comment: All right I'll try to do that sir